# Jira - release deployment to UAT/Production

Tags: workflow, jira, release-management

Do you know how to mark a release that it is deployed to System test/UAT/Production? I would like to filter on stories deployed to different environments. Is it possible?
I do not want to handle this as workflow as I want to avoid cases when two stories are assigned to the same release but one story is on UAT while and other one is not.

Thanks
Zoltan

Answer (score 0):

Your example is confusing, as if you have two stories in the same release I would see each story as being their own issue. You could then still use workflows as each issue can be in a different status than the other. Workflows are good if you are moving through environments in a specific order such as:

```
Open -> Dev in Progress -> QA -> UAT -> Pre-Prod -> Prod
```

If you want it so an issue could be on multiple environments at a time, then I would use a custom field like Checkboxes:

```
Deployed to:
  [*] Dev
  [ ] QA
  [*] UAT
  [ ] Pre-Prod
  [ ] Prd
```

Then you could do your filter for Issues like:

```
project = 'TEST' and release = '1.0' and Dev is not Empty and UAT is not Empty
```

To see all issues for the Test Project that are in Release 1.0 and are on Dev and UAT.